# Add custom CSS for plugin admin Page

Tags: plugin-development, admin-css

I am trying to add custom CSS for plugin admin Page. If I use below code then it is working.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'cricket-info-admin-styles', plugins_url('') . '/wp-cricket-info/assets/css/admin_styles.css', false, '1.0.0', 'all' );
```

But if I use below code it is not working.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'cricket-info-admin-styles', plugins_url('wp-cricket-info/assets/css/admin_styles.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all' );
```

Why second code is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using this code in a **wrong file** other than the main plugin file (usually `/wp-content/plugins/wp-cricket-info/wp-cricket-info.php`). So, the file you're referencing when enqueueing is actually incorrect.

Follow the steps below-

1. Define a constant in the main plugin file that references the file itself.

`define( 'WP_CRICKET_INFO', __FILE__ );`

2. When enqueueing the CSS, use that constant as the second parameter.

`wp_enqueue_style( 'cricket-info-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'assets/css/admin_styles.css', WP_CRICKET_INFO ), false, '1.0.0', 'all' );`

Answer (score 3):

It's likely because [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/) returned an *invalid URL* like so: ( note the `wp-cricket-info/wp-cricket-info/` )

`https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-cricket-info/wp-cricket-info/assets/css/admin_styles.css`

So if you specify the 2nd parameter, which is a full path to a file inside a plugin or mu-plugin, then the 1st parameter should be a path *relative to the directory of that plugin*.

- **Correct:** `plugins_url('assets/css/admin_styles.css', __FILE__)`
- **Incorrect:** `plugins_url('wp-cricket-info/assets/css/admin_styles.css', __FILE__)`

And with `plugins_url('')`, your code worked correctly because the directory (`wp-cricket-info/`) was not "doubled".

Comment: Thanks @Sally CJ. If I use this code `wp_enqueue_style( 'cricket-info-admin-styles', plugins_url('assets/css/admin_styles.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all' );` then I am getting output `http://127.0.0.1/wordpressbosta/wordpressplugincricket/wp-content/plugins/wp-cricket-info/inc/Admin/assets/css/admin_styles.css?ver=1.0.0`. But I need output `http://127.0.0.1/wordpressbosta/wordpressplugincricket/wp-content/plugins/wp-cricket-info/assets/css/admin_styles.css?ver=1.0.0`. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, then you would want to define a constant which stores the full absolute path to the *main plugin file*, e.g. if the file is at `wp-content/plugins/wp-cricket-info/wp-cricket-info.php`, then add `define( 'WP_CRICKET_INFO_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );` at the top in that file. Then pass that constant to `plugins_url()`, i.e. `plugins_url( 'assets/css/admin_styles.css', WP_CRICKET_INFO_PLUGIN_FILE );`.

Comment: Or you could define the full URL to the plugin folder, e.g. `define( 'WP_CRICKET_INFO_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );`, and use that constant from within any PHP files in your plugin folder, e.g. `WP_CRICKET_INFO_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/css/admin_styles.css'`.